# PHP Fatal Error: "Unable to parse ..file.. as the file is not readable"

Tags: php, apache, composer-php

I'm trying to run this app: http://gaspaio.github.com/gearmanui

I'm on digitalocean with apache, cloned repo, installed composer and restarted apache.

So I'm getting blank screen and this error on apache logs:

```
[Wed Jul 30 14:39:56.444638 2014] [:error] [pid 8731] [client 123.123.123.123:57826] PHP Fatal 
error:  Uncaught exception 'Symfony\\Component\\Yaml\\Exception\\ParseException' with message 'Unable 
to parse "/var/www/html/src/GearmanUI/../../app/config/gearmanui.yml" as the file is not readable.' in
/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/yaml/Symfony/Component/Yaml/Yaml.php:98\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/
src/GearmanUI/ConfigurationProvider.php(30): Symfony\\Component\\Yaml\\Yaml::parse('/var/www/html
/s...')\n#1 /var/www/html/vendor/silex/silex/src/Silex/Application.php(160): 
GearmanUI\\ConfigurationProvider->register(Object(GearmanUI\\GearmanUIApplication))\n#2 /var/www
/html/src/GearmanUI/GearmanUIApplication.php(41): Silex\\Application->register(Object(GearmanUI
\\ConfigurationProvider))\n#3 /var/www/html/web/index.php(5): 
GearmanUI\\GearmanUIApplication->__construct()\n#4 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/vendor/symfony
/yaml/Symfony/Component/Yaml/Yaml.php on line 98
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you follow the steps in Configuration on that page you linked?

Comment: yes. I guess this is an issue with apache

Comment: Check file permissions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make sure your file is readable by the server, try CHMODing it to 700 or so. If you're not sure how, you can usually do it via your FTP client by right clicking on the file and choosing "File Permissions"

Comment: solved by uploading everything with filezilla, thanks